# 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, frontend

Im trying to access some api's, and here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content=
    "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
    <title>JavaScript | fetch() Method</title>
</head>
  
<body>
    <script>

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Origin','http://localhost:3000');
        // API for get requests
    let fetchRes = fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: headers});

    // fetchRes is the promise to resolve
    // it by using.then() method
    fetchRes.then(res =>
        res.json()).then(d => {
            console.log(d)
        })
    </script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

and this works fine.
However when i replace the prev api url with this https://flask-heroku1p.herokuapp.com/add/3,5 (we created this api in https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/flask-restful-api-with-heroku-da1ecf3e04b)
It gives me this err:

[image]

Comment: Check out this article:
https://wirescript.vercel.app/blog/top-five-cors-issues-you-dont-want-to-run-into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need credentials to access the heroku site. Removing the line `credentials: 'include',` or setting `credentials: 'omit',` will solve your issue.